# C# Non Blocking, forward only, XML parsing

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to parse XML data received from network stream (XMPP). The problem is that I want to account for the event when the XML is chunked in packets so that the received data stops within a tag. Something like this.

```
<node a='aa' b=
```

then after a while

```
'bb' />
```

Now the XmlReader will block until the last packet arrives.

Thinking about this, I figured that I need one of the following:

1- A push based (event based) parser similar to SAX, but with added functionality that I can feed the parser chunks of data, and the parser fires events when tags complete, keeping the incomplete chunk.

2- A pull model like XmlReader, but with added `bool HasNext()` function which return true when there are enough data to `Read` without blocking.

I searched a lot and found neither in the framework or in separate libraries. Any insights are most welcome.

Note: I am well aware of other solutions like spawning a separate blocking thread, which I don't want to do, or `async` solutions that I don't want to use because this code will be run in Console apps.

Regards

Comment: But, `async` *does* sound like the right tool for this job. It can be used just fine in console apps. What are your hold-ups regarding it?

Comment: To be honest, I come from C++ background and I don't like it that much. But more importantly, async propagate, and that puts requirements on client code, which I prefer to avoid.

Comment: Unless your client has very specific requirements, I would say when you're doing I/O it's better now to offer async support than to force people down a sync route. You can see Microsoft's projects, like HttpClient, are moving in this direction already. Don't try to mimic C++. Be native to C# -- mimic the .NET framework. I come from a C++ background too. Did you know a variant of async/await is being proposed for the next C++ standard?